# SMTP mail error in Opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: smtp, opencart, opencart2.x

When I try submit email in contact page I have get following error in **OpenCart 2.0.3.1**

> Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known in /[path]/system/library/mail.php on line
>   170 Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com
>   :465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service
>   not known) in /[path]/public_html/muadoan_com/system/library/mail.php
>   on line 170 Notice: Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known (0) in
>   /[path]/public_html/muadoan_com/system/library/mail.php on line 173

In setting, I set protocol SMTP,

- hostname : ssl://smtp.gmail.com
- username : myemail@gmail.com
- password : myemailpassword
- port: 465

I searched and found that someone had this issue but with the older versions of opencart.

Anyone helps me please?

Comment: Your network isn't properly configured.  Not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

Grep the code from document root directory with:

```
grep -R "'config_mail_smtp_host'" *
```

In the files found replace `$this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_host')` with `$this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname')`

On this issue see [here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/2840), but you can find more files, probably.